# AngularJs Beginner, how to call a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using for the first time AngularJS. I want to make a year scrollbar from 1960 to 2010. I need to recover the value of ng-bind, in order to call my function updateData(year) when I move the scrollbar. But I have a problem...

I guess that the script is uncorrect. Can you help me?

```
<div ng-app>
    <input id='slider' type='range' min=1960 max=2010 ng-model='year' width=200>
    <span ng-bind='year'></span>
    <script>
    updateData({{year}})
    </script>
    <div id='' class='rChart datamaps'></div>  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Html :**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
    <input id='slider' type='range' min=1960 max=2010 ng-model='year' width=200>
    <div>
        {{updateData()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js :**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.year = "2000";
    $scope.updateData = function() {
        return "Year : "+$scope.year;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/28Lgcyoc/

Answer (score 0):

Just call like **`{{updateData(year)}}`**. And make sure the updateData function is it in `$scope` in your controller. Then only you access in the view html part. Otherwise You Can't Use in html.

```
<div ng-app>
    <input id='slider' type='range' min=1960 max=2010 ng-model='year' width=200>
    <span ng-bind='year'></span>
    {{updateData(year)}}
    <div id='' class='rChart datamaps'></div>  
  </div>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.updateData = function() {
   return 'Hello';
}
```